Is Richard Carrier right in saying that it is obvious that god is more complicated than the universe?
In his blog here, Carrier responds to The Routledge Handbook of Contemporary Philosophy of Religion edited by Graham Oppy where the authors state that it is not obvious that God’s mind would be more complex than the known universe.
He states,

Richard Dawkins is credited with making something akin to this same argument. Though he’s not the most careful of thinkers. There is an attempt at responding to it in his form in The Routledge Handbook of Contemporary Philosophy of Religion edited by Graham Oppy, but it mostly just takes advantage of Dawkins, for want of being a practiced philosopher, being his own straw man.

Continued later..

There they claim it is not obvious that God’s mind would be more complex than the known universe, for example. But it is obvious. Because the contrary is actually logically impossible. It is a well-known law of computer science that the simplest computation for simulating a system, is the system itself (see Labyrinths of Reason on this point). In other words, it requires a more complex computer to simulate a world, than the world simulated. Simply because you have to have all the complexity of that world, plus the added complexity of the infrastructure of simulating it. As in God’s case, not only must God’s mind contain all true information about the universe, which is logically necessarily identical in complexity to the universe thus known, but his mind will also contain all true information about all other possible universes. This he needs in order to decide which is the best universe to make, and the best actions to take to maintain it (which knowledge, requires comparing one choice with all others, so as to discover the best). But even if he didn’t know any of that (a fact that would substantially diminish his divinity), his mind must contain all true information about himself. Thus, his mind cannot avoid being more complex than the universe…which for its entire existence and operation requires no added information about gods.


Dougherty and Gage absurdly think they can refute this by jotting down on a piece of paper “God knows everything” and thereby prove God is simpler than “everything” (they ask us to start our list of “everything” with aardvarks). This is phenomenally stupid. Obviously the word “everything” is just an artificial code that’s hiding a vast complex of things…starting with aardvarks. You can’t claim God is simple because the word “everything” is simple. That word may be one word, of only ten letters. But its kolmogorov complexity is vast. Try describing an information system that contains “everything” and you’ll start to see the problem. Even if you can come up with a simpler algorithm that, when run to completion, would produce “everything” (aardvarks and all)—though good luck with that—you still end up with a complex result. Where are you going to store all that information? Not in anything simple. You can’t fit “everything” into 128 megabytes of RAM. But moreover, you then have to admit the universe is itself already governed by such an algorithm. And it is necessarily simpler than any mind could ever be.


Because again: the mind has to have all the added complexity (of being a mind, and not a mindless universe) on top of the information known (the code for the unfolding the universe, which itself is obviously not conscious of itself, or anything). Thus, even if you can come up with a simpler algorithm by which God knows everything, it must still be more complex than the thing known: the algorithm that would by itself produce everything, without God. “But you need God to write that algorithm!” Yeah. Exactly. Which requires more complexity in God, than could possibly be in that algorithm. See the problem?

Does this imply that god's mind is necessarily more complex/improbable than anything it tries to explain within the universe?

@KristianBerry I suppose his gripe with that would be similar to his gripe with Dougherty jotting down "God knows everything". It is one thing to be able to write that or to claim that God knows things through His one pure act. It is a whole different thing to outline and explain how it is done. Without which you don't really have an explanation. As an analogy in the same blog, he states, "Try coding “car, roll uphill” with just the words “car, roll uphill,” without any underlying operating system (much less physical processors and memory chips). Nothing will happen. Because it can’t."

@KristianBerry We don't have to know how God does things to establish the conclusion that however it is done, it must be more complex than the universe (according to Carrier). In regards to your point about computer science, I think that is just semantics. The universe is not literally a physical computer but it can clearly be modeled by certain laws and constants for example, and so one can use computer science concepts to talk about this information system even if it literally doesn't run on a processor.

He does talk about this in the blog though: "Because all worlds are just computers. Whether simulated or real, all any universe is, by definition, is just an information processor and a system of information. We call the processor “the laws and constants of physics” and the information “facts.” But it’s still just a computer. It is no more logical to expect the universe to manifest supernatural phenomena, than it is to expect a computer to obey commands with no operating system..."

Why would any supernaturalistic dualist ever grant the premise that a mind is a computer?

I'm fairly certain the claim that "all knowing is computing" can be reduced to "all is number". In which case I'd be happy to grant that if all is number, then God, if he is as usually described, must be a very long number. And then promptly deny that that means anything useful, since I don't see any reason to grant that all is number.

This whole argument is philosophical BS. It's based on some shallow pop-knowledge of information theory but has no relation at all to (or value for) either actual cosmology or religion. This is why serious people turn away from philosophy.

@mudskipper okay what’s simpler than the thing itself then? Don’t just spout shit without backing it up

It depends on what you mean by God and what you mean by complicated, and whether you take the view that God transcends human logic.
If you take the view that God is a figment of human imagination, then the question is irrelevant.
If you take the view that God created the Universe, then that does not in itself require God to be more complicated than the Universe.
If you take the view that God understands everything, and has a knowledge of every configuration state of the universe and more besides, then God must be more complicated than the Universe.
If you believe that God transcends human logic, then the question becomes meaningless.

Carrier's argument is fairly well conceived, even though it is not explicitly clearly articulated.  I will try to spell it out more explicitly than he has, and add in omnipresence too, as that gets one to the same place as omniscience does:

IF there is a God who is omnipresent in the universe, then God by definition cannot be less complex than the universe.
If an omnipresent God has any capabilities beyond that of the universe, or any thoughts about the universe, then such a God must therefore be more complex than the universe.



Thinking about something involves creating a mental model (simulation) of that thing.
The simplest simulation that fully captures all aspects of what a thing is, is the thing itself.
Omniscience includes the ability to be aware of all aspects of the world simultaneously.
If there is a God who is omniscient, that God must have a mental model of the universe, which cannot be any less complex than the universe.
Provided God has other thoughts as well, then God must be more complex than the universe.

In classical theism, God is postulated to be both omnipresent and also omniscient in the way assumed by Carrier.
Under classical theism, Carrier's argument is quite good.
However, most Gods postulated throughout history have not been either omnipresent, nor omniscient in the mode assumed in classical theism.
For example, once could postulate a Deist creator God who is only required to be more complex than the standard model of quantum physics, and is neither omnipresent, nor omnipotent even in a more limited sense.  Such a God would not know nor be able to predict how emergence created all the complexity of our world from the relative simplicity of the Standard Model.
Or, once could postulate a similar creator God with an additional limited knowledge thruput capability, plus the ability to probe any question or aspect of the universe, and understand it serially, rather than simultaneously.  Such a Deist God would be Omniscient in a way.  Eventually.  But once more such a God would not be as complex as the universe.
So Carrier's argument is only as good as the argument for classical theism.  If one does not concede classical theism, then his conclusion does not follow.

+1 "Or, once could postulate a similar creator God with an additional limited knowledge thruput capability, plus the ability to probe any question or aspect of the universe, and understand it serially, rather than simultaneously" On a metaphor, consider that an author could write a volume of encyclopedias. Would we expect that author then after the fact to recall of the information? Reason successfully about any of the information? Exhibit the level of expertise without the references handy in the spirit of extended cognition? Of course, not. God's mind could be very unsophisticated, but...

Having been at work 100 billion years before setting the universe in motion, accumulated enough activity and effect to bring the complexity to where it is today.

You do also need to concede that knowing something necessarily involves thinking about it, and that thinking about something necessarily involves creating a simulation of it, if you want the premise in the first bullet point after the break.

Consequently I think your statement that "Under classical theism, Carrier's argument is quite good" doesn't follow and mars an otherwise good answer. The classical theist ought to deny or at least seriously doubt the claim that even a human mind knows only by thinking and thinks only by computing, let alone the divine mind.

@gs The best ontology and epistemology I have found is Popper's three world theory, plus his conjectures and refutations. Under C&R, what our minds do for us functionally is find and then use world 3 hypotheses, which can be functionalized. I know that some are non-verbal, as 3D object transforms and looking at sunsets are non-verbal. But the transforms in particular, plus things like map reading, are "operational" and therefore functional.  Also despite being in a private language, we can translate them into our public language.  So I have no objection to the postulate 2.2.  What is yours?

@dcleve "knowing is only thinking-about" is a claim that needs defending, v knowing-as-being and knowing-as-doing; "thinking-about is simulating" is a claim that needs defending, v simulating being just one kind of thing that thinking-about can be or can do; and "simulating is computing" is a claim that needs defending v simulating can or does involve computing (and I think that one is completely indefensible: no computation has ever simulated anything, computers or on-paper calculations are tools of conscious minds, which then map the mathematical objects to hypothetical physical objects).

...or v knowing as potential for certain kinds of thinking-about

And I don't see any reason why anyone would even take the claims seriously except while playing under the rules of mechanistic naturalistic monism. But under those rules, "Supernatural being is ___" is a phrase that doesn't mean anything since no supernatural being is, so discussing theology is meaningless noise until we abandon the rules of mechanistic naturalistic monism, and the claims along with them.

@gs Well, Popper was an emergent dualism triplist, not a monist, and I am a spiritual dualism triplest not a monist, and Wanna be monist Jaegwon Kim actually objected to functionalism because he considered it to be intrinsically dualist with matter, so I don't think that there is anything like a consensus agreeing with you that functional/computational views of what thinking involves is necessarily mechanistic monism.

Meanwhile, the excellent work documented in Thinking Fast and Slow, and in Incognito show how our unconscious neurology does a lot of processing that is passed to our consciousness intuitively.  That we have intuitions that are not explicitly modeled in our consciousness, does not mean that there isn't a model somewhere in our conscious plus matter minds.    It is a bonus that both books describe how our combined minds work in terms that are best described as a "homunculus" steering a meat machine ...  The best of modern mind science is arriving back at Descartes.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think a philosophical concept from Jain philosophy can clarify matters here. They said that some thimgs can be described and other things are indescribable. God is one such thing. God is indescribable.
This is in contrast to the Western philosophical tradition who described God as simple. By this they mean that God cannot have parts. He is a whole unto Himself. However, this language is in sharp contrast to the conventional meaning of simple which is opposed to complex. How can God, who created the universe, be simple? This is where the Jain language is better suited. God is indescribable. Whereas the universe is describable. Your headline question is:

Is Richard Carrier right in saying that it is obvious that god is more complicated than the universe?

By the above argument, yes.

How do you distinguish between the indescribable and non existent?

Not familiar with Jain philosophy, but I suspect this is a close counterpart to mystery in the Christian philosophical tradition. The meaning is a property, known to be true because of divine revelation, which cannot be apprehended by reason. So we would say that some of God's properties are mysteries, from which we can infer that God is indescribable in the sense that, although we can identify his revealed properties, we cannot apprehend what those properties mean functionally.

@MargaretPierce if that's the same concept used here, the difference is that only existent things can be indescribable because only existent things have properties other than not existing. And all nonexistent things are describable, since they only have that one easily apprehended property.

@gs that tells you what the difference between a non existent and an existent thing is. It doesn’t tell you how to distinguish between them in the sense that when one says X is non existent, you can claim that X is indescribable. I suspect that god being seen as indescribable is simply a tactic to prevent its incoherence or evidence-less nature from being seen.

@Margaret Pierce: Something that is non-existent is not indescribable. Properly speaking it is not describle as there is nothing to describe.

On the level of the Question itself is it not clear, either Carrier is correct or the debate is endless?
It's easy to argue, only a more complex creator could make (anything).
It's easy to argue, luck or accident played their part.
It's easy to point out that living in three spatial or four space-time dimensions seems to be no barrier to imagining more or, had we the power, creating them.
On the gripping hand, why might God not be equally complex as, when using an absurd example, any number of scientists spend their lives trying to clone people, restore extinct species or more wildly, to create new life?

There is no being right or wrong about this. The truth of statements would depend on precise models and definitions, and theology does not have precise models and definitions about god. As an example "omnipresence" lacks a model. If a god is present everywhere, in what way are there present? Are they present in every atom and subatomic particle, or only present in every cube inch? How much of an omnipresent god fits on the pin of a needle is not specified. Also being present in a place does not need to imply being active or aware of things in that place, my toe nail might be dipped in water without me noticing. So those words can mean whatever any speaker wishes them to mean any given time. Those words are adaptable to any purpose, which helped churches justify contradictory positions over time. This they needed to wield and grow their political and economical power.
The various paradoxes around all those Omni... Words also show they lack formal validity. A contradiction allows inferring any statement and it's opposite.
The 4 big Omni... Attributes are also not well-defined in the Bible, but merely poetically alluded to in ambiguous ways, and have thus been invented later in non-revelation by non-proohet organizations. No prophets after Jesus in Christianity, about which we seem to talk. The Quran seems to add some of its own, but really any person is free to add their own. If I want to declare the gods are Omnifunny, making only the best jokes, there is no formal constraint to show me wrong. Like nobody's going to cite the Bible where God made a very bad joke to show that god is not Omnifunny.
So theology is just a house of cards of words that lack enough specificity and a model for how to relate to the universe in any specific way.
This theoretic self-indulgent construct of words called theology does not allow to make much logical inference. That is not a flaw to theologicians, the churches are not interested in making their gods formally defined entities, but theology likes to keep gods always somewhat out of reach.
One thing is clear however, these definitions of God are clearly not very complex, the average recipe for a sourdough bread as an example is more complex than the definition of God, and experts have debated for centuries on how to make the perfect sourdough bread.  So all of theology is simpler than that, and does not produce any bread.

A few suggestions. The Bible precedes the development of Classical Theism, which is based on the later writings of Plotinus.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotinus  Therefore its God descriptions not being fully consistent with classical theism is unsurprizing. Also, Paul explicitly claimed his own writings to be God-inspired in one of his letters, which would make him a post-Jesus prophet. Acts also describes the holy spirit entering the disciples and inspiring their worlds, making them at the time also prophets.  Christianity does not make a big deal of this, but some figures fit the term.

Further, linguistic specificity is not needed for a theory to be useful, and model the world.  Our science theories are simpler than the world is, but they provide us massive utility. That we keep finding areas where they break down, and need further addendum, does not change their prior extreme usefulness.  Absolute precision and specificity is an unnecessary threshold for utility.  If you throw out theology based on not meeting it, you also throw out science.

Note science is also incomplete, and is not self-coherent.  One can only make local logical inferences that are valid based upon its theories.  They all break down at some point when globally extrapolated.  Your declaration that theology is useless based on this property is also refuted by science having the same one you object to.

I don't need a black-and white view on this. I can accept that everything is a shade of grey, with theology about as useless as black as coal, and science as white as an eggshell, neither being perfectly black or white. Still this allows to completely dismiss theology as utter crap not worth anyone's time. So you're attempt to cling at straws by saying "But science is also not perfect" is as useless as it is pathetic.

Pointing out that your post is based on assuming falsehoods and reasoning fallacies is not clinging to straws.  Your maintaining your invalid anti-theology conclusion, despite your rationale being exposed as entirely based on falsehoods and fallacies, is just to double down on irrationality, and is characteristic of one in the grip of an irrational ideology.

Thanks for letting me know.
